# How to extend access token validity ?

Tags: facebook

As we know that offline_access is deprecated now can some one tell me that how can we get the long lived access tokens without that permission?

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9712663/122978

Answer (score 1):

You can extend the access token by adding the following function to the base_facebook.php.

// Extended Function for extending the token values.

public function getExtendedAccessToken()
{

```
try {

    $access_token_response =
        $this->_oauthRequest(
            $this->getUrl('graph', '/oauth/access_token'),
            $params = array(    'client_id' => $this->getAppId(),
                                'client_secret' => $this->getApiSecret(),
                                'grant_type'=>'fb_exchange_token',
                                'fb_exchange_token'=>$this->getAccessToken(),
                          ));

} catch (FacebookApiException $e) {

  return false;
}

if (empty($access_token_response)) {
  return false;
}

$response_params = array();
parse_str($access_token_response, $response_params);
if (!isset($response_params['access_token'])) {
  return false;
}

return $response_params['access_token'];
```

}