# Getting new extended 60 day Facebook token

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm following the method outlined here to extend tokens to 60 days:

https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/

In other words, I call https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?
    client_id=APP_ID&
    client_secret=APP_SECRET&
    grant_type=fb_exchange_token&
    fb_exchange_token=EXISTING_ACCESS_TOKEN

with the current access token.

First time I tried this, it actually worked fine and the token was extended for 60 days. Now it doesn't seem to work anymore, even though several days have passed since the last time I requested an extension. You're supposed to be able to extend once every 24 hours if I'm reading this correctly...

...anyone else seeing this?

Answer (score 0):

Please see the following post, I have extended the access token validity and it works fine for me.

[How to extend access token validity ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10247108/how-to-extend-access-token-validity/10248902#10248902)

Comment: That code is similar to what I'm trying... same endpoint. Only worked for me the first time I tried it. Are you able to re-extend tokens every 24 hours?