# Getting Offline_Access using Facebook Graph API

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook-graph-api

I found this article that shows you step by step of how to get the offline-access token but im stuck on the last part what is the long_facebook_code from the url i provide you below

https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=xxx&redirect_uri=xxx&client_secret=xxx&code=long_facebook_code

I understand the client_id, redirect_uri and client_secret but what do i enter for code?

The article is here http://webddr.net/tips-and-tricks/facebook-offline-access-step-by-step-explanation/

Comment: @tomhallam, i have posted the article link. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Don't spent your time to learn more about offline_access permission,
cause Facebook has announce the removal of this permission method.

https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/

all the access_token's will expire after 60 days.

Comment: whats the url i need to pass to get the access_token to expire in 60 days? Thanks

Comment: you will need the PHP SDK, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5155487/access-token-expire-time-with-offline-access-permission