# Problems with extending Facebook access token on iOS after the offline_access permission was depreciated

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, facebook-ios-sdk

I'm trying to figure out how my iOS app should work after Facebook make
the **offline_access** permission deprecated. [Docs](https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/) are unclear and I read
them all a couple of times.

What I'm trying to do is:

1. I authorise my iOS app with FB:

   `[_facebook authorize: [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"email", @"publish_stream", @"user_birthday", nil]];`
2. Then, I request the `"me"` from graph API to get the FB ID cause I need
   it:

   `[_facebook requestWithGraphPath: @"me" andDelegate:self];`
3. Then in:

   `-(void)request: (FBRequest*)request didLoad: (id)result`

I check the expiration date of the token

```
if ([_facebook.expirationDate timeIntervalSinceNow] < 60*60*24) // 1 day 
{ 
   [self extendAccessTokenWithAppID:kFacebookAppID 
                          appSecret:kFacebookAppSecret     
                      existingToken:_facebook.accessToken]; 
}
```

My method that extends the token simply contacts the endpoint which is
described in the docs I mentioned at the beginning.

```
-(void)extendAccessTokenWithAppID:(NSString*)appID appSecret:(NSString*)appSecret existingToken:(NSString*)existingToken 
{
      NSString *requestString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"oauth/access_token?client_id=%@&client_secret=%@&grant_type=fb_exchange_token&fb_exchange_token=%@", appID, appSecret, existingToken];

      [_facebook requestWithGraphPath: requestString andDelegate: self]; 
}
```

I handle the response in

```
- (void)request: (FBRequest*)request didLoad: (id)result
```

but what I get is always the same token and the same expiration date that I passed to the endpoint. The expiration date is never extended and is just a short 1-2 hours (normal for short lived
access token). This means that the token was not extended.

I have **Remove offline_access permission** set to **Disabled**.

Do you know what can be wrong in my approach? Thanks for any help!

P.S
I found similar questions on StackOverflow but none of the answers is working for me, e.g.
[Access Token expire time with offline_access permission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5155487/access-token-expire-time-with-offline-access-permission)

**Update:**

Enabling the **Remove offline_access permission** makes FB return only long lived tokens. I tested this by creating a new FB account and logging with this account in my app. I was given the long lived token straight away.

With **Remove offline_access permission** disabled FB gives me only short lived access tokens, even if I try to extend the short lived token using the endpoint provided in the docs. The endpoint returns same token with the same expiration date.

The crucial problem is that I cannot test the scenario when FB gives me short lived access token and I contact the endpoint to extend it to be long lived access token. Seems like FB developers are not ready for the feature they want to introduce.

Comment: _“I have Remove offline_access permission set to Disabled.”_ – you want to __enable__ it.

Comment: I see it, after enabling it the app was given the long lived token straight away. The problem is I cannot test the normal path when the user is given the short lived token and then I extend it by contacting the endpoint. Do you know how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Things to check which could be causing you problems here

1. You have disabled offline_access in the advanced settings of your app
2. You're using the most recent copy of the SDK. It's currently unversioned, but older copies won't support the access token extension
3. You've configured SSO per the [instructions in the docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/ios/build/#implementsso)
4. You've waited until a user's token expires entirely - you may be getting 'new' short tokens because you're retrying, but once the token expires entirely, you should get a longer token the next time the user comes back

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'm a little bit confused now. I set the "Remove offline_access permission" migration to enabled and my app was given a long lived access token straight away without giving it a short lived token? Should this migration be Enabled or Disabled? Cause for me it's unclear after reading the docs. Cheers! :)

Comment: It's phrased strangely, but 'remove offline_access permission' being 'enabled' is what marks your app as one which is ready for the new 'short /long' token model

Comment: Ok, now I get it. But how can i test it to see if my token extension code is working? Now, FB gives me the long lived access token instead giving me the short lived one (so I can extend it). Thanks!

Comment: You'll have to wait a while to see it actually happen, but it should be possible to extend the next time the user comes back, assuming they're still logged into Facebook

Comment: I created a new FB account to test if I get the short lived token but it didn't happen. FB gave me 60 day token - this means that I can't test if extending the token actually works. I should just hope that my app will work when FB starts to return extended tokens from the endpoint... eh :/. Anyway, Thanks a lot @Igy for your help! It clarified a lot!